# Turning on certain UISwitch but not all programmatically

Tags: swift, uiswitch

I'm trying to create multiple UISwitchs but I'm trying to only turn on certain switches. 
I only want to turn on the switches that are in both of the arrays (weightUnits and allUnits).
anyone, that knows how i can do this?

```
let weightUnits = [ UnitMass.kilograms, UnitMass.stones, UnitMass.pounds, UnitMass.ounces ]
@objc func weightLong(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer){
    if sender.state == .began{
        createOptionView(weightUnits)
    }
}
fileprivate func createOptionView(_ units: [UnitMass]) {
    for view in infoStack.subviews {
        //cleans the infoStack to make it ready for the new units.
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    let allUnits = [ UnitMass.grams, UnitMass.kilograms, UnitMass.metricTons, UnitMass.stones, UnitMass.pounds, UnitMass.ounces ]
    for unit in allUnits {
        let prefix = unit
        let newOptionCard = UIStackView()
        newOptionCard.axis = .horizontal
        newOptionCard.alignment = .trailing
        newOptionCard.distribution = .fill
        let option = UISwitch()
        for usersUnit in units {
            if allUnits.contains(usersUnit){
                option.setOn(true, animated: false)
            }
        }
        newOptionCard.addArrangedSubview(option)
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
        label.text = " " + prefix.symbol
        label.textColor = .white
        label.font = UIFont(name: "American Typewriter", size: 20)
        label.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 60))
        newOptionCard.addArrangedSubview(label)
        infoStack.addArrangedSubview(newOptionCard)
    }
}
```

[image: how it looks now]

Comment: Sorry, can you please elaborate why you need to check if a unit is contained in both arrays, given that apparently weightUnits are all included in allUnits?

Comment: I have two different arrays since i have one array with all the different units that the user can choose from. the array weightUnits are containing the units the user has chosen. @GregdeJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a way to do this. The error i had was that i didn't use the isEqual but so i didn't compare the whole object.

```
for usersUnit in usersUnits {
            if unitOption .isEqual(usersUnit){
                option.setOn(true, animated: false)
                break
            } else {
                option.setOn(false, animated: false)
            }
        }
```